# Add input field in Ext.tab.Panel

Tags: extjs

I am creating a menu using `Ext.tab.Panel` and would like to have Search feature. Something like Bootstrap navbar - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

I tried to simply add the `textfield` element but didn't work obviously.

```
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    fullscreen: true,

    items: [{
            title: 'Home',
            iconCls: 'home',
            html: 'Home Screen'
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact',
            iconCls: 'user',
            html: 'Contact Screen'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'name',
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            allowBlank: false // requires a non-empty value
        }
    ]
});
```

Is it possible to achieve this at all?

Comment: It works: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2nls

Answer (score 1):

You can archive it with the [tabbar config](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.tab.Panel.html#cfg-tabBar) of the `Ext.tab.Panel`.
The [Ext.tab.Bar](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.tab.Bar.html) is a specialized `Ext.container.Container` where you can add items like a to `Textfield`.

So add te search textfield to the tabbar config and you can archive what you want to, see the example code below and the [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2nme).

```
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    fullscreen: true,

    items: [{
            title: 'Home',
            iconCls: 'home',
            html: 'Home Screen'
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact',
            iconCls: 'user',
            html: 'Contact Screen'
        },
    ],
    tabBar: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'name',
                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                allowBlank: false // requires a non-empty value
            }
        ]
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At first this functionality does not exist in the tabpanel, which I recommend you do and replace the idea of ​​tabpanel to apply a cardlayout which is the same tabpanel layout system.

And then you can use a toolbar, with the buttons being configured with the toogleGroup, in short, you'd better see the code example below working.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            fullscreen: true,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                height: 42,
                defaults: {
                    xtype: 'button',
                },
                items: [{
                    text: 'Tab1',
                    handler: function(button){
                        var me = this,
                            fakeContainer = button.up('panel').down('#fakeTab');
                        fakeContainer.setActiveItem(button.tabIndex);
                    },
                    tabIndex: 0,
                    toggleGroup: 'tabHandler',
                    enableToggle: true,
                    pressed: true,
                    margin: '0'
                }, {
                    text: 'Tab2',
                    handler: function(button){
                        var me = this,
                            fakeContainer = button.up('panel').down('#fakeTab');
                        fakeContainer.setActiveItem(button.tabIndex);
                    },
                    tabIndex: 1,
                    enableToggle: true,
                    margin: '0'
                }, {
                    text: 'Tab3',
                    handler: function(button){
                        var me = this,
                            fakeContainer = button.up('panel').down('#fakeTab');
                        fakeContainer.setActiveItem(button.tabIndex);
                    },
                    tabIndex: 2,
                    toggleGroup: 'tabHandler',
                    enableToggle: true,
                    margin: '0'
                }, '->', {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Search:',
                    labelWidth: 70,
                    width: 250,
                    margin: 0 
                }, {
                    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-search',
                    handler: function(){
                        alert('Your Search here!');
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'container',
                itemId: 'fakeTab',
                margin: '16 0 0 0',
                flex: 1,
                layout: 'card',
                defaults: {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    height: 800
                },
                items: [{
                    html: '<STRONG>TAB 1 your content here</STRONG>'
                }, {
                    html: '<STRONG>TAB 2 your content here</STRONG>'
                }, {
                    html: '<STRONG>TAB 3 your content here</STRONG>'
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Working sample [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2nlv)